# How to create an inverted U graph?

Tags: diagrams, plot

I just wonder how to make something like this, but I am not sure what package I can use? Thanks [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE! You have many choices: `tikz`, `pgfplots`, `pstrics`, ... to number few of them.

Comment: @Zarko I tried to use pgfplots but I am not sure how to get rid of the numbers on both axis? I want only the greek letters to appear, any idea?

Comment: Please, add to your question what you try so far. With see this (as small complete document) we can easy help you (and add those Greek letters).

Answer (score 5):

As Zarko said in a comment there are some different versions to use. Below is first one example using Tikz, then the same using pgfplots. Since you have not specified much I have taken a normal x^2 plot.

**Tikz**

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,declare function={F(\x) = 1.7*(2*\x-\x*\x)-0.2;}]
  \draw[-latex] (0,-0.2) -- (0,2) node[left]{$f(x)$};
  \draw[-latex] (-0.2,0) -- (2,0) node[below]{$x$};
  \draw[domain=0.1:1.9,samples=10,smooth,thick] plot (\x, {F(\x)});
  \coordinate (max) at (0,{F(1)});
  \draw[dashed] (max) -| (1,0) node[pos=0,left]{$\beta$}node[pos=1,below]{$\mu+\alpha$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**pgfplots**

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={F(\x) = 1.7*(2*\x-\x*\x)-0.2;}]
  \begin{axis}[%
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$f(x)$,
    xmax=2,xmin=-0.2,ymax=2,ymin=-0.2,
    axis lines=center,axis line style={-latex},
    ticks=none,
    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.0)},anchor=east},
    ]
    \addplot[domain=0.1:1.9,samples=10,smooth,thick] {F(x)};
    \coordinate (max) at (axis cs:0,{F(1)});
    \draw[dashed] (max)  -| (axis cs:1,0) node[pos=0,left]{$\beta$}node[pos=1,below]{$\mu+\alpha$}; 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here a solution using `pstricks`:

Thanks to Stefan providing a function ;-)

**PSTricks**

```
\documentclass[border=15mm,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{psgraph}[arrows=->,labels=none,ticks=none,yAxisLabel=$\beta$,](0,0)(2,1.9){0.8\linewidth}{7cm}%
 \psplot[algebraic]{0.1}{1.9}{1.7*(2*x-x^2)-0.2}
 \psCoordinates [linecolor=blue,linestyle=dotted,] (*1 {1.7*(2*x-x^2)-0.2})
 \psxTick(1){\mu+\alpha}
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

[image]